# Как в selenium python включить настройку использования куки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Долгое время не понимал почему куки не загружаются, решил залезть в настройки вебдрайвера остановив код и выяснил что куки там просто не включены[image: введите сюда описание изображения] , однако опции при загрузке как в хроме я найти не смог, что делать? Как включить?

Comment: Вставь картинку понормальному и посмотри на текст того что там на картинке

Comment: @eri Перевставил, спасибо за напоминание - я забыл что тут можно не ссылкой вставлять, и причём тут текст?

Comment: "выберите трекеры и скрипты которые необходимо блокировать"

Comment: скорее всего вы не правильно создаете драйвер